# Go Error: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference. Changing map inside a struct which is present in another struct,

Tags: go

I have to structs lets say struct1 and struct2, struct2 contains a map with struct1, struct1 also contains a map, I want to change the map which is present in struct1.

This is throwing a runtime error:
*panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference*

```
type FailureData struct {
    failuresInCommits map[string][]string 
}

type DetectionResults struct {
    Failures map[git_repo.FilePath]*FailureData
        //Have other things
}

func (r *DetectionResults) Fail(filePath git_repo.FilePath, message 
           string, commits []string) {  
        ok := r.Failures[filePath].failuresInCommits //error occurs here    
        if r.Failures[filePath].failuresInCommits == nil {       
            r.Failures[filePath].failuresInCommits = make(map[string][]string)
        }
        if len(ok) == 0 {
            r.Failures[filePath].failuresInCommits[message] = commits
        } else {
            r.Failures[filePath].failuresInCommits[message] = 
               append(r.Failures[filePath].failuresInCommits[message], 
                      commits...)   
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you write will not pop nil error while compiling.It only causes nil point error when you are using it in a wrong way.

`failuresInCommits map[string][]string` did you use it after `make()`?

`Failures map[git_repo.FilePath]*FailureData` did you use this after 'make()'?

ok , now you focus on 
`ok := r.Failures[filePath].failuresInCommits`,did you make sure `r.Failures[filePath]` returns 'failuresIncommits, true',

if not, then r.Failures[filePath] is nil, ok, you tell me what is `nil.failuresInCommits`.

there is also a risk that you can only x.failureInCommits in this specific package. If you do the same in some other package, x.failureInCommits will be unaccessable becaues of the field lowwer case limited.

How to make ?

```golang
package main

type FilePath string

type FailureData struct {
    failuresInCommits map[string][]string
}

func NewFailureData() FailureData {
    return FailureData{
        failuresInCommits: make(map[string][]string, 0),
    }
}
func (fd *FailureData) Set(k string, v []string) {
    fd.failuresInCommits[k] = v
}

type DetectionResults struct {
    Failures map[FilePath]*FailureData
    //Have other things
}

func NewDetectionResults() *DetectionResults {
    return &DetectionResults{
        Failures: make(map[FilePath]*FailureData, 0),
    }
}
func (dr *DetectionResults) Set(fp FilePath, fd *FailureData) {
    dr.Failures[fp] = fd
}

func main() {
    fd := NewFailureData()
    dr := NewDetectionResults()
    comments := []string{"push error", "commit error", "add error"}

    fd.Set("hash-18ef8abujce8fad0h8j", comments)
    dr.Set("/etc/go/gopath/src/github.com/xxx/xxx/main.go: 12", &fd)
}
```

Comment: I have this function for creating the struct, I'm unable to use make for the inner struct "*FailureData"   

`func NewDetectionResults() *DetectionResults {  
 result := DetectionResults{make(map[git_repo.FilePath]*FailureData), 
                                                           make(map[git_repo.FilePath][]string)
                                                   }  
 return &result  
}`

Comment: @MohammadAbdulBari I've refreshed the answer to show how to use the struct you define